# SBT multi project in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Im trying to use a single Intellij IDEA window with multi projects (that are not related) imported. 
The problem that I'm facing is when I'm executing a `sbt task`, the task is not loaded in the right project directory.

This is what I did (all in the Intellij Idea window):

1. Opened a `root` empty sbt project.
2. In the sbt toolbar, I clicked the `+` and added 2 projects `job-service` and `user-service` (each was its own `build.sbt` file)
3. Pressed `Reimport All sbt projects` just for fun
4. Executed `compile` (from the sbt toolbar) for the `user-service`

The sbt shell opened, and started compiling the empty root project:

```
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/Users/dima/git/root/)
[IJ]sbt:root> compile
```

what I've expected is

```
[info] Set current project to user-service (in build file:/Users/dima/git/user-service/)
```

*And of course, the same for the second project `job-service`*

**Versions:**

```
Idea version: Version: 2019.2 Build: 192.5728.98
SBT version = 0.13.18
```

I know the way to use a single `build.sbt` file with multi projects. But those projects are not related. each project has its own `build.sbt` file. 
I just want to use a single Idea window with multiple projects. and that the sbt toolbar could execute the tasks to the right project

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

This is the process to recreate what I'm facing:

1. [open project named root2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkNZC.png)
2. [Import another sbt project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE6dN.png) called `learner`
3. [Compile the learner project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU0XI.png) **from the sbt toolbar!**
4. The Problem: [sbt shell sets current project to root2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ft2d.png)

the same for `publishLocal` task. it sets the current project to root2 and publishes a root2 artifact. 
what should have been, is that the sbt would set the current project to `learner`

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem on IntelliJ some time ago, but in that moment my project was not `sbt` related. That project contains two different applications in different programming languages, so they could not have a common build file.

But I've found a solution to solve this problem which was using IntelliJ `Modules`. These `Modules` will let you create different projects inside your current workspace.

You can access it in **File** -> **Project Structure...** -> **Modules** (In the left panel)

I think you can use this feature to accomplish your expected result. Hope it helps!

Comment: Tried that.. its just like the `+` button in the sbt toolbar.

if you say it works for you (and the projects are in different language), so im trying to think that its an sbt toolbar problem , that it cant load the right project when executing the sbt task

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this? two diff shells for different projects or running two different projects sbt commands from same shell ? I can add the projects as modules like the above answer but not run commands like `assembly` for each.